# Mongoose 500 error after inserting the data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I post the form I am getting 500 error on console that says: `POST/items/sprinkler 500    angular.js:10766`.

In my node console the error says: `Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory`.

But I am able to insert the data to my database. After that this doesn't run- `exec(function(err, item)`. How do I go about with this?

mainapp/routes/items.js

```
router.post('/sprinkler', function(req, res) {
    Item.create(req.body).exec(function(err, item) {
      console.log("printed")
      res.json(item)
  });   
});
```

my error handler looks like this(from express itself):

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    console.log("message from error handler:")
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Your server is trying to render an error page (presumably because of an error caused in your handler, perhaps a validation issue?), but it can't because of a missing error template. You should either fix the error handler of your Express app, or remove it so it will crash your server with the actual error.

Comment: I tried writing this 'if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(500);
            }
            else {
                console.log(saved);
                res.send(saved);
            }`  but it shows the same. Also I added an error page in my views/500 but it again shows same error.

Comment: The error happens _before_ that code. I'm talking about the global Express error handler, documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: When I refresh the page the data saved is getting back on my views as it is. Still i am getting error when I post.

Comment: fix your express error handler so that you can get an error message. until then, there's nothing anyone can do to help you.

Comment: I am very new to express, how can I fix the error handler. my error handler looks like this: if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    console.log("message from error handler:")
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

Comment: Make an error view that gets rendered by `res.render('error',..)`, or remove that and log the error directly. Get your hands dirty, get in there and change some code around until you understand what it is doing. Don't be scared to try fixing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the error is caused by this:

```
Item.create(req.body).exec(...)
```

[`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) returns a promise, and `.exec()` isn't a valid method for promises.

To fix this, you have two options:

```
// Use a callback
Item.create(req.body, function(err, item) { ... });

// Use the returned promise
Item.create(req.body).then(function(item) { ... }, function(err) { ... });
```

However, this leaves the issue with the error handler not working properly because of a missing template (had that been working, you would have probably gotten an error that pointed towards `.exec` not being a function).

Instead of a template, you can log the error, or return it as JSON (or both):

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.json({
      message : err.message,
      error   : err
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You are 100% correct. That's it. I used the callback `Item.create(req.body, function(err, item) { ... });`. I am able ti get the data on the front end too. I was doing res.send (error handling part) but when I started the server, it would shut down with error. You method is perfect. And thank you for teaching me error handling too.